# Routing not working with php WAMP and angular without .php

Tags: php, angularjs, routes

`localhost/test/dash.php` => working 
`localhost/test/dash#`  => not working

This should open the angular framework. But its working only with `.php`

I am using `php 5.6 wamp`

what can be the problem?

My `.htaccess` not affects at all

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Please post your angular routing system.

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Angular. What **exactly** does *"not working"* entail?